# failed to connect to xxxxx:xxxx in 150000ms node mssql

Tags: node-mssql

I have a node js job. This job is using node-cron to run some logic in every hour.
It's connecting to sql server database using node mssql package.

connection file code:

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
const conn = (function () {
    try {
        return new sql.ConnectionPool(obj);
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}())


const pool = (function () {
    try {
        return conn.connect();
    }
    catch (err) {
       throw err;
    }
}());



const myConn = async function getConn() {
    try {
        return await pool;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};

module.exports = {
    myConn    
}
```

Code to call stored procedure:

```js
async function callProc(procedureName, inputList, callback) {
    try {
        const pool = await connectionFile.myConn();
        const request = new sql.Request(pool);
        if (inputList) {
            for (const param of inputList) {
                request.input(param.name, param.type, param.value);
            }
        }
        const result = await request.execute(procedureName);
        callback(null, result);
    }
    catch (err) {
        callback(err, null);
    }
}
```

Intermittently my job is failing with error "failed to connection to  in 15000ms"

Any suggestion?

Comment: why are you wrapping them calls in IIFE's?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  This is existing code. can you please give more details on what is it and what problem it can cause?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone IIFE is used so pool is always available once job is started.

Comment: where is obj set?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it's an object I am setting in connection file. object has server and account details.